# Setting the class/innerHTML of a table with ng-click()

Tags: angularjs

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in vm.contacts">
  <td ng-click="clickedOn(this)" ng-repeat="weekDay in vm.daysOfTheWeek">
    <span>
      <a>
        {{innerHTML}}
      </a>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Okay, so how do I select a td? I'm overwhelmed here. I want ng-click to change the {{innerHTML}} of that single element, but it's a nested ng-repeat... so I can't just do magic to both the 'employee' and the 'weekDay' at the same time?

Comment: Try `ng-click="clickedOn($event.target)"`. What is `innerHTML` and where does that come from?

Comment: Error: [$parse:isecdom] Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed! Expression: clickedOn($event.target) Am I doing it wrong? lol

Comment: Oops, that's what I get for guessing. You can try just passing the `$event` to your `clickedOn` function however I feel there's probably a better way to do what you want. Again, where does `innerHTML` come from? What **exactly** do you want to have happen when you click a `<td>`?

Comment: Basically I want it to say "Working 7am to 5pm" if they click there http://i.imgur.com/tgmCpsv.gif

Answer (score 0):

This will give each td a unique id.

```
<td ng-class="td-{{$index}}">
```